# How to embed a custom cocoa framework to mac os x application?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have created a Cocoa framework for an OS X application.

I now want to add my framework to a different Xcode project and used this tutorial, http://jaanus.com/blog/2014/07/09/how-to-correcty-configure-building-private-slash-embeddable-os-x-frameworks/

However I am getting the following error,

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/TestFrame.framework/Versions/A/TestFrame
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users/sfm/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestApp-byxusmdybnklhceubusavrswfxtr/Build/Products/Debug/TestApp.app/Contents/MacOS/TestApp
>
> Reason: image not found

I assume the install path has to be changed in the Framework build setting project not the application build setting project. Can any body guide me what am i doing wrong as I am new to Mac OS X development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post you link kind of breezes over the "Copy Files" step. Did you actually follow that?

> We add a new “Copy Files” phase to bundle the framework into the application.

You should look in your app bundle (on disk) and see if there is a `Contents/Frameworks/TestFrame.framework` directory. I'm betting there isn't.

Xcode has gotten a bit better about configuring frameworks automatically. I recommend consulting the Framework Programming Guide, specifically [Embedding a Private Framework in Your Application Bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880) which has a bit more modern instructions.

Comment: I have used the same. Xcode which i am using is 5.0.2. Will this make any difference? Okay will look in to what ever information you have shared

Comment: I can't remember exactly how framework handling has changed over the versions, but as I recall, the 6.x line is much better about it. I would definitely recommend upgrading in any case.

Comment: I am now working in VM ware and the OS is mavericks. Could u please guide me doing the following
You must configure the build phases of your application target to put the framework in the correct location.
You must configure the framework target’s installation directory, which tells the framework where it will live.

Comment: These are walked through in the next sections ("Using a Single Xcode Project For Both Targets" and "Using Separate Xcode Projects For Each Target"). I will note that as a beginner in OS X dev, it is seldom worth the trouble to create a framework. In the vast majority of cases, you should just put all the files you want into your main project. Frameworks are fairly complex to manage, and of dubious utility in my experience, particularly if you are not part of a large, multi-team organization.